# Knockout + large dataset performance

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, haversine

I have a very large lat/long dataset which I'd like to be able to filter and display client side. I've profiled and optimised the best I can, but **is there is anything further than can be done to speed up performance?**

- Accuracy needs to be at the mile/kilometre level.
- I'd need IE 7/8/9/10 support although I'm accepting the further down we go the performance will likely get worse.
- I have not absolute dependency on any library, whatever is best for the job.

**Roughly**

- Chrome: 1.1s
- Firefox: 0.9s
- IE10: 5.1s
- IE9: 3s

http://jsfiddle.net/hRvKz/

```
// Apparently I must post code... but out of context it would make no sense.
// Checkout jsfiddle.
```

Comment: Any reason you can't do the filtering on the server?

Comment: I'm experimenting to see if I can make client filtering faster than server post back filtering factoring in a bit of latency. The servers are based in the US, users are global.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code creates a dependency between the criterias and each sample.
I created a computed function in order to create a dependency between criterias and the samples array. This, in order to create only a few dependencies.

The modified code takes only **20ms** against **2700ms** for the original.

```
viewModel.computedLocations = ko.computed( function () {
    var lat = viewModel.filters.lat();
    var lng = viewModel.filters.lng();

    var locs = viewModel.locations();
   ko.utils.arrayForEach(locs, function (item) {
        item.roughDistance = equirectangularApproximation(item.lat, item.lng, lat, lng);
        item.closeDistance = sphericalLawOfCosines(item.lat, item.lng, lat, lng);
        item.closeDistanceStatic = item.closeDistance;
        item.exactDistance = haversine(item.lat, item.lng, lat, lng);
    });
    return locs;
});
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hRvKz/4/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Very nice. I was working down a similar path as you posted this, thanks!